# Prove $\sup _{t \in [0,1]} |P(t)|$ is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be the vector space containing all polynomials with real coefficients. For every $P \in X$, define $N_1 (P)=\sup _{t \in [0,1]} |P(t)|$

I am having trouble proving the part when you show $||P||=0 \iff P=0$.

So $\|P\|= N_1(P)=  \sup _{t \in [0,1]} |P(t)|$

($\implies$) Let $\|P\|=0$, then $\sup |P(t)|=0$, which forces $P(t)=0$ for all $t$ in our region. Hence $P=0$

($\impliedby$) Let $P=0$, then $P(t)=0$ for all $t$. So $\|P\|=N_1 (0 ) = \sup |0| = 0$ as required.

My lecturer said that this is not enough. She also said that in the forward direction, I cant really conclude that $P=0$...

Can someone give a full proof of this please.

Comment: "My lecturer said that this is not enough." is peculiar. On the other direction,  do you think that a polynomial vanishing at all points of $[0,1]$ should vanish everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because she is considering that all your polynomials are polynomial functions defined in all of $\Bbb R$. You have shown that $P$ is zero on all of $[0,1]$ but not on all of $\Bbb R$. But a degree $n$ polynomial is determined by its value on $n+1$ distinct points. Certainly $[0,1]$ has more than $n+1$ points, for all $n \geq 0$, so it follows that $\sup_{t \in [0,1]}|P(t)| = 0$ implies $P(t) = 0$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$ (which is stronger than the $P(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$).

---

($1$): About $P(t)$ being determined by its values on $n+1$ points: write $P(t) = a_0+a_1t+\cdots +a_nt^n$. If you know $y_0 = P(t_0), y_0 = P(t_1),\cdots, y_n = P(t_n)$, then you can solve the system $$\begin{cases} P(t_0) = y_0 \\ \vdots \\ P(t_n) = y_n\end{cases}$$for $a_0,\cdots, a_n$, and then you know $P(t)$ for *all* values of $t$.

($2$): About the analysis far from $[0,1]$ being important: you can define non polynomial functions ($C^\infty$, etc) that are non-zero outside $[0,1]$, but zero on $[0,1]$ - your proof would fail if we were working with arbitrary bounded functions instead of polynomials.

The point is that $P\big|_{[0,1]} \equiv 0 \implies P\equiv 0$ uses strongly the fact that $P$ is a polynomial, so we can apply fact $1$ above.

Comment: What if I did the following. She did something similar but that was for $||f||_{\infty}$ and i mimicked the idea: Assume $P \in X$ and $||P||=0$. We want to show that $P(t)=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: Consider $h(t)=|P(t)|$. Assume $\exists t \in (0,1)$ such that $c=h(t) \neq 0$. Since $h$ takes only nonnegative values, we get $c \geq 0$. By continuity of $h$, $$\exists \varepsilon, \, \, \forall x \in (t- \varepsilon, t+ \varepsilon ) \subseteq (0,1): \, \, h(x) > c/2$$ As $h \geq 0$, we get $$0 = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} h(x) \geq \sup_{t \in (t- \varepsilon , t+ \varepsilon )} h(x) \geq c \varepsilon > 0 $$ a contradiction. This proves $h(t)= |P(t)|=0$ for all $t \in (0,1)$, thus $P \equiv 0$ by continuity at $0$ and $1$. Is this OK?

Comment: Um, I don't think so. What you've done before already shows that $P \equiv 0$ in $[0,1]$, ok, but what about very far from $[0,1]$?

Comment: what do you mean by But a degree 
n
 polynomial is determined by its value on 
n+1
 distinct points?

Comment: A degree $n$ polynomial has $n+1$ coefficients $a_0,\ldots, a_n$. If you have the value at $n+1$ points, you can solve the system for the coefficients, determining the polynomial.

Comment: But i don't understand what that has got to do with anything... Is there any chance you can elaborate in your answer please? As much as you can cuz clearly I'm dumb.

Comment: I edited some things in the answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, i do understand a bit more now. So what you have done, is this only for the forward implies? Is my backward implies good enough?

Comment: Yes, I commented only on the forward direction. Your work on the backwards direction is fine (I would only add the step $P = 0 \implies P\big|_{[0,1]}$ before saying $N_1(P) = 0$, but this is not important)

Comment: Can i ask, what does that line next to P mean?

Comment: It indicates the restriction of $P$ to $[0,1]$.